# Largest possible worm?

Tags: science-based, biology, zoology

Earthworms can reach 22 feet in length, nematodes can grow to 27 feet, tapeworms can reach 130, and some ribbon worms can stretch 180 feet. In my world, I want giant worms with hundreds of feet long to exist, similar to a few movies like [Dune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(2020_film)). That said, on a planet with earth-like conditions, is it possible for a worm-like creature to reach such incredible lengths? I'd prefer an answer that states which environmental pressures would prevent it from growing up to further lengths.

Comment: As you've already seen, there's nothing stopping worms from going to well over 100ft, the problem with giant worms isn't the length, it's the diameter.

Comment: Related question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/160805/what-theoretically-is-the-limit-or-max-size-and-length-for-a-serpent-worm-before

Comment: I would imagine that a [Titan Boa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanoboa) would be above that max size due to supporting rib cage.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza thats the question I posted, pretty much the same question as OP's.

Comment: @RandySavage I saw your comment and voted to close as a duplicate. That comment was automatic. I've never voted to close as dupe before so I didn't realize it would do that.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Ah fair play, don't think I have the rep to vote to close yet, the question does seem to be answered in many forms in different questions, that one we mentioned is pretty on the money, but there may be other solutions.